# Cannot type a space in TinyMCE editor

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

I have recently come across the problem of not being able to add spaces in inline TinyMCE editable areas.

As you can see below, the top 3 navigation items are editable when clicked and you can type any characters, however when you select the "Thislinkcannotcontainspaces" link you cannot add any spaces.

They both use the same `data-editable` minimal attribute, they both are hooked into `a` tags, both within an `li`, I am completely out of ideas as to why this is happening.

The expected behavior is all the nav elements are editable with any characters including the space.

```js
tinymce.init({
  selector: '[data-editable-minimal]',
  inline: true,
  toolbar: false,
  menubar: false
});
```

```css
h2.mce-content-body {
  font-size: 200%;
  padding: 0 25px 0 25px;
  margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
}

body {
  background: transparent;
}

.content {
  overflow: visible;
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  margin-left: 0;
  min-height: auto;
  padding: inherit;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="//www.tinymce.com/css/codepen.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-user">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">

      <!-- Collapsed Hamburger -->
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#app-navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="app-navbar-collapse">
      <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#" data-editable-minimal>Forums</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" data-editable-minimal>A Link
            <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu open show">
            <li><a href="/" data-editable-minimal>Thislinkcannotcontainspaces</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/" data-editable-minimal>A link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there is a conflict within `bootstrap`. When using the dropdown module of `bootstrap` it overrides certain keys when dropdowns are open, as of v3.3.7 it overrides the key codes `38|40|27|32`

Answer (score 0):

Per the TinyMCE documentation inline mode is intended to function on block level elements only.  The `<a>` tag is not a block level element so its not surprising this would not work.

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/editor-appearance/#inline

The `<li>` tag is a block level element so if you use that instead do your result change?

Comment: As you can see in the demo, it is attached to multiple `a` tags and they are working fine. I could understand if none of them worked but that is not the case.